# Runaway argument in pgfmodulshapes.code.tex

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

While trying to compile the file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[active,textmath]{preview}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
$\kappa$
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex
Runaway argument?
Header: /cvsroot/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \next was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.11
```

The same code works fine with TeXLive 2013, but not with TeXLive 2014 & 2015 where the newest versions of chemfig & tikz are included.

(Yes, this is correct code, no chemfig is actually used, it is just included in preamble).

Would appreciate any hints how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the manual mentions

> `textmath` will make all text math subject to previews. Since math mode is used throughly inside of LaTeX even for other purposes, this works by redefining `\(, \)` and `$` and the math environment (apparently some people use that).
>   Only occurences of these text math delimiters in later loaded packages and
>   in the main document will thus be affected.

As mentioned in the last part. You have to load the preview as the last package if possible.

But in general you can switch to `standalone` document class instead of `preview`.